# Link_to(image_tag ...) works locally but breaks on Heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

pretty simple bit of ruby code is working fine when run on localhost but breaks when pushed up to heroku. Here it is:

```
<ul>
  <% @regulars.each do |r| %>
    <li>
      <%=h link_to (image_tag small_avatar_url(r.user), :class => "u_profile_img_small", :title => r.user.name), r.user %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And here is the error in Heroku Logs referring to the link_to line above:

ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1))...

What gives? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have multiple encapsulated method calls, Ruby needs the proper parentheses so it knows which arguments go with which method. You can have the first method call without parentheses (`h` in this case), but the rest are needed.

`<%=h link_to(image_tag(small_avatar_url(r.user), :class => "u_profile_img_small", :title => r.user.name), r.user) %>`

Answer (score 1):

I think the parentheses are throwing off your `link_to` call. Try tightening it up like this:

```
  <%=h link_to(image_tag(small_avatar_url(r.user), :class => "u_profile_img_small", :title => r.user.name), r.user) %>
```

Note: You may not want to be using `<%=h` as that will escape the `<` and `>` in your generated link.

Comment: Tightening up the parens worked. Did not need to remove the <%=h. Thanks a ton!